# Is there a word for the memory of a place that no longer exists?

Tags: meaning, terminology

My secondary school was destroyed, I still remember the layout of the building and can walk through it in my mind. Is there a word for this? Other than nostalgia?

Comment: I'd say that's... a memory.

Comment: Maybe let me rephrase this slightly, a word that describes the emotion attached to remembering somewhere that no longer exists?

Comment: memory is memory. Whether a place still exists is not a memory issue.

Comment: A sentence would help clarify. The current answer doesn't match the guidance in the comments.

Comment: @TylerChi. Excellent question and it's a word that should be ferreted out. In the meantime, consider "chronophobia": the fear of time passing. In V. Nabokov's Speak Memory, which is all about things remembered but vanished from reality (a way of life, etc.) he uses it to describe himself (cleverly disguised) as a child looking at old photo albums and being struck by the absence of himself, the onset of his consciousness of time. It's not quite what you want (I'll keep searching), but it does encompass the unsettling feeling of having memories of things that no longer exist.

Comment: @Jim A memory can be of something that still exists or doesn't exist. The OP is asking for a word that represents or evokes the latter, a refinement of memory.

Answer (score 1):

The school no longer exists. The place becomes a **phantom** in your mind. You can only experience it as a memory or in imagination.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/phantom)
>
> phantom noun [Countable]
> something that appears or seems to exist but is not real or is imagined

*Phantom may also be used as an adjective:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phantom#:%7E:text=delight%E2%80%94%20William%20Wordsworth-,phantom,2%20%3A%20fictitious%2C%20dummy%20phantom%20voters)
>
> phantom adjective:
> of the nature of, suggesting, or being a phantom : Illusory

Another adjectival example is:

> [Mayo Clinic](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/phantom-pain/symptoms-causes/syc-20376272)
>
> Phantom pain is pain that feels like it's coming from a body part that's no longer there.

Hence your memory of the school is a phantom, or a phantom school.